# PHP throwing errors on simple select queries?

Tags: php, forms, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

Not sure what's going on, I keep getting errors. I have reduced the problem down to quite a small test-case, see below:

---

**login.html**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" required />
    <input type="password" name="password" required />

    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

**login.php**

```
$email    = $_POST["email"];
$password = sha1($_POST["password"]);

$stid2 = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT EMAIL, PASSWORD FROM TUSERS where EMAIL =: email AND PASSWORD =: password');
oci_execute($stid2);

$nrows = oci_fetch($stid2);

print var_dump($nrows);
```

**Errors**

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound in login.php on line 5
>
> Warning: oci_fetch(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in login.php on line 7 bool(false)

Comment: its var_dump() not vardump(), to lazy to explain the rest.

Comment: don't you have to bind email and password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added variable placeholders into the query but didn't bind anything to them

```
$stid2 = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT EMAIL, PASSWORD FROM TUSERS where EMAIL =:email AND PASSWORD =:password');
oci_bind_by_name($stid2, ':email', $email);
oci_bind_by_name($stid2, ':password', $password);
oci_execute($stid2);
```

See [oci_bind_by_name](http://www.php.net/oci_bind_by_name)

Comment: Thanks, also does the binding do anything related to sanitisation? - If not, what do I use for that?

Comment: As you can see, query string and variable contents are defined separately, the library which works with the db knows which is which. Query and data might be sent to the dbms in separate queries even(if the dbms supports it). So at least this is going to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I suspected as much; unfortunately I don't have rep here otherwise I would upvote your answer and comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the variables $email and $password to the oracle placeholders. see [oci_bind_by_name](http://www.php.net/oci_bind_by_name). Also, the placeholder should be `:email` and `:password`. You have a space between the colon (`:`) and the placeholder name (`email` and `password`).